# How to efficiently solve an inequality where the variable occurs in the denominator?

Tags: inequality

For example, this inequality:
$$\frac{2x(x-4)}{x-1} \le 7$$

I can solve this by finding the 'critical values' (or in other words, two values which $x$ can/or cannot equal), then putting them on a number line and testing values on either side of these two numbers.

However, I don't understand how you would solve this inequality by using the "multiply by the square of the denominator, then sketch a parabola and use the x-intercepts to solve" method.

Nor do I understand how to solve this following the 'two cases' rule where if $\frac ab \le 0$ then either 1. $a<0, b>0$ or 2. $a>0, b<0$.

Feel free to tell me any specific 'prerequisite knowledge' I should have or other concepts that I should be confident with to solve inequalities with a variable in the denominator.

By the way, please explain every step (explain why you would do it) included in your method because I'm terrible at maths. I can't wrap my head around the concept of inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide into two cases:

- $x-1>0$: Multiply each side by $x-1$, and solve $2x(x-4)\leq7(x-1)$
- $x-1<0$: Multiply each side by $x-1$, and solve $2x(x-4)\geq7(x-1)$

To summarize this, you will have to compute the range of valid values for $x$ as follows:

$$([x-1>0]\cap[2x(x-4)\leq7(x-1)])\cup([x-1<0]\cap[2x(x-4)\geq7(x-1)])$$

---

Let's solve the left half:

- $[x-1>0]\cap[2x(x-4)\leq7(x-1)]\implies$
- $[x-1>0]\cap[2x^2-8x-7x+7\leq0]\implies$
- $[x-1>0]\cap[2x^2-15x+7\leq0]\implies$
- $[x-1>0]\cap([x\leq\frac{15+\sqrt{15^2-4\cdot2\cdot7}}{2\cdot2}]\cap[x\geq\frac{15-\sqrt{15^2-4\cdot2\cdot7}}{2\cdot2}])\implies$
- $[x-1>0]\cap([x\leq7]\cap[x\geq\frac12])\implies$
- $[1<x\leq7]$

---

Let's solve the right half:

- $[x-1<0]\cap[2x(x-4)\geq7(x-1)]\implies$
- $[x-1<0]\cap[2x^2-8x-7x+7\geq0]\implies$
- $[x-1<0]\cap[2x^2-15x+7\geq0]\implies$
- $[x-1<0]\cap([x\geq\frac{15+\sqrt{15^2-4\cdot2\cdot7}}{2\cdot2}]\cup[x\leq\frac{15-\sqrt{15^2-4\cdot2\cdot7}}{2\cdot2}])\implies$
- $[x-1<0]\cap([x\geq7]\cup[x\leq\frac12])\implies$
- $[x\leq\frac12]$

---

So the range of valid values is $[x\leq\frac12]\cup[1<x\leq7]$.

Comment: I don't know how to solve 2x(x-4) >= 7(x-1) or 2x(x-4) >= 7(x-1). Where do I start?

Comment: @Sad: Expand the expression and put everything on one side. You'll have a quadratic expression on that side. Solve the quadratic and draw a parabola so that you can determine the solutions.

Comment: @Sad: Oh... I thought your problem was with the inequality. I didn't realize you were not able to handle a quadratic formula. I will update the answer...

Comment: @Sad Confer my answer. You subtract the RHS to get the form $ax^2 + bx + c \le 0$

Comment: @barakmanos: Okay, I did all the steps up but got confused at the part where you use the quadratic formula. Like I get that you sub all the values into the formula but specifically, I wanted to ask why you put x>= and x<= for the positive and negative solution and vice versa (if that makes sense) ... I'm really confused. Sorry. It would be great if you could explain it in a way that a 3rd-grader would be able to understand. My knowledge of maths is really, really limited.

Comment: @Sad: I completely understand what part you've failed to understand (probably because I have not explained it in great details). The coefficient of the "strongest term" in the equation ($x^2$) is positive ($2$). Therefore, the parabola has a minimum point. All the values of the parabola for $x$ which is between the roots are negative. All the values of the parabola for $x$ which is smaller than the smaller root or larger than the larger root are positive. I could have use the derivative of $2x^2−15x+7$ in order to provide a formal proof, but it seemed to becoming too detailed at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply both sides by the positive number $(x-1)^2$, resulting in the inequation:
$$2x^3-17x^2+22x-7<0.$$
Then graph the cubic curve (it's not a parabola) $y=2x^3-17x^2+22x-7$. The solutions are the abscissae of the points of the curve that are *below* the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

## Quadratic inequalities

To find a solution to
$$ax^2+bx+c \le 0$$
(or $\ge 0$) you need to determine the roots by solving $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ for $x$. Now if there are two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x_1<x_2$, the real line is divided into three intervals,
$$\mathbb R = (-\infty, x_1] \cup [x_1, x_2] \cup [x_2,\infty)$$
Now look at the leading coefficient $a$. The sign of $a$ determines the sign of the quadratic in the outer intervals. The inner interval has reversed sign. If there is only one (or no) root, the inner interval vanishes and the sign is determined by $a$ on all of $\mathbb R$. A table:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{ineq.}&a>0&a<0\\
\hline
ax^2+bx+c \ge 0&(-\infty, x_1] \cup [x_2, \infty)&[x_1, x_2]\\
ax^2+bx+c\le 0 &[x_1,x_2]&(-\infty, x_1]\cup[x_2,\infty)
\end{array}
$$

## The specific inequality

Generally, this will involve a case differentiation. I'll walk through your example to illustrate. Note that $a < b \Leftrightarrow \cases{ac<bc & if $c>0$\\ ac>bc & if $c<0$}$.

$$\frac{2x(x-4)}{x-1} \le 7$$
**Case 1:** $x < 1$
$$2x(x-4) \ge 7(x-1) \Leftrightarrow 2x^2 - 15x - 1 \ge 0$$
$\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty, \frac12] \cup [7, \infty)$. Since we assumed $x< 1$ we obtain the solution
$$((-\infty, \frac12]\cup[7,\infty)) \cap (-\infty, 1) = (-\infty, 1)$$.

**Case 2:** $x > 1$
$$2x(x-4) \le 7(x-1) \Leftrightarrow 2x^2 - 15x - 1 \le 0$$
The solution to the quadratic gives us $[\frac12, 7]$, so in total we get
$$[\frac12 , 7] \cap (1, \infty) = (1,7]$$

The complete solution set is now given by the union of all cases:
$$(-\infty,1) \cup (1,7] = (-\infty, 7] \setminus \{1\}$$